# Golang using lowercase for first letter in Struct property

Tags: mysql, templates, web, go

I have an issue with Golang view template, I currently using lowercase in the struct properties to build the struct then passed it to the view as a map.

here is my Struct look like:

```
type User struct {
      uid                  int
      username, departname string
}
```

then I passed the collection of structs to the file view:

```
func (App *App) indexHander(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      rows, err := App.db.Query("SELECT * FROM userinfo")
      checkErr(err)

      t, _ := template.ParseFiles(App.folderpath + "/list.gtpl")

      users := make([]User, 0) // define empty collection of users

      for rows.Next() {
          var uid int 
          var username string
          var departname string
          var created string
          err = rows.Scan(&uid, &username, &departname, &created)
          checkErr(err)
          users = append(users, User{uid, username, departname})

      }   

      t.Execute(w, users)

      defer rows.Close()
  }
```

**and here is my view html code:**

```
<html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <ul>
          {{ range  . }}
             <li>{{ .username }}</li>
          {{ end }}
          </ul>
      </body>
  </html>
```

Those code above gave me empty users data:
[image]

But however, using capitalize first letter in struct give me working result:

**Struct**

```
type User struct {
     Uid                  int
     Username, Departname string  
}
```

**html**

```
<html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <ul>
          {{ range  . }}
             <li>{{ .Username }}</li>
          {{ end }}
          </ul>
      </body>
  </html>
```

**it works now**

[image]

Can somebody explain me this behavior ?

Comment: This is the Go property. Struct First character must be a capital letter.

Comment: You can see lower case properties as *private* (not exported) : https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers

Comment: Just wondering why the compiler allows for unusable/inaccessible struct values that begin with lowercase letter? It allows it. There's no error when defining or access these values. However the data goes into the void it seems.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the doc [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers):

> An identifier may be exported to permit access to it from another
> package. An identifier is exported if both:
>
> - the first character of the identifier's name is a Unicode upper case    letter (Unicode class "Lu");
> - and the identifier is declared in thepackage block or it is a field    name or method name.    All other identifiers are not exported.

Comment: In Go, an identifier that starts with a capital letter is exported from the package, and can be accessed by anyone outside the package that declares it it.

If an identifier starts with a lower case letter, it can only be accessed from within the package.